# CSRF | When the cookie(key 'route') expires. ERROR: The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, csrf

When the cookie(key 'route') expires. Then asp.net mvc 4 gives this error.

> The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted. If this application is
> hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that all machines are running
> the same version of ASP.NET Web Pages and that the 
> configuration specifies explicit encryption and validation keys.
> AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

Is there any fix for this problem?
Thank you!

Comment: This issue related to machinekey. [Please check this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28210911/7687666)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.