# SignalR issues with URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm having an issue that I can't seem to figure out. Thank you for any assistance you may provide.

I have a Server 2008 R2 SP1 server that is running a .net application that we are trying to implement SignalR on. It works on 1 of the 3 servers. The URL I have is

> http://%SITENAME/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.4&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22mediahub%22%7D%5D&_=1452535854677

The error I found in the logs is

```
2016-01-11 12:56:58,506 [65] ERROR ASP.global_asax [(null)] - 
MESSAGE:     A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&).
SOURCE:      System.Web
URL:         http://%SITENAME%/signalr/negotiate clientProtocol=1.4&connectionData=[{"name":"mediahub"}]&_=1452536862615
REFERRER:    
FORM:        
QUERYSTRING: 
TARGETSITE:  Void ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()
STACKTRACE:     at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context)
= = =
```

Its on a server 2008 R2 sp1 server. I've found lots of instructions but haven't found this issue specifically.

Comment: Are you sure ? Is this path of url `http://%SITENAME%/signalr/negotiate clientProtocol=1.4&connectionData=[{"name":"mediahub"}]&_=1452536862615` ?

Comment: I did sanitize the url from the client url from the top link. I did notice the ? Drops in the error message but it's part of what may be broken so I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

I went into the web config and turned on displaying the compilation errors. I hit this url http://%SITENAME/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.4&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22mediahub%22%7D%5D&_=1452535854677  and got an error about the machine.config key. After googling the error, I removed the ,IsolateApps from the web.config on the servers.

Here is the link I followed.

[IsolateApps causes Decryption key specified has invalid hex characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002960/isolateapps-causes-decryption-key-specified-has-invalid-hex-characters)