# SignalR - Decryption key specified has invalid hex characters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config, signalr

I am using SignalR 2.2.0 and MVC 4. When I load my page in Chrome, I receive an error in the console:

```
http://localhost:8180/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22chathub%22%7D%5D&_=1467627883530 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Upon further inspection using Fiddler I can view the stacktrace:

```
[ConfigurationErrorsException]: Decryption key specified has invalid hex characters. (C:\Users\Foo\web.config line 66)

   at System.Web.Security.Cryptography.MachineKeyMasterKeyProvider.GenerateCryptographicKey(String configAttributeName, String configAttributeValue, Int32 autogenKeyOffset, Int32 autogenKeyCount, String errorResourceString)
   at System.Web.Security.Cryptography.MachineKeyMasterKeyProvider.GetEncryptionKey()
   at System.Web.Security.Cryptography.Purpose.GetDerivedEncryptionKey(IMasterKeyProvider masterKeyProvider, KeyDerivationFunction keyDerivationFunction)
   at System.Web.Security.Cryptography.AspNetCryptoServiceProvider.GetNetFXCryptoService(Purpose purpose, CryptoServiceOptions options)
   at System.Web.Security.Cryptography.AspNetCryptoServiceProvider.GetCryptoService(Purpose purpose, CryptoServiceOptions options)
   at System.Web.Security.MachineKey.Protect(ICryptoServiceProvider cryptoServiceProvider, Byte[] userData, String[] purposes)
   at System.Web.Security.MachineKey.Protect(Byte[] userData, String[] purposes)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.DataProtection.MachineKeyDataProtector.Protect(Byte[] userData)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection.AppBuilderExtensions.CallDataProtectionProvider.CallDataProtection.Protect(Byte[] userData)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.DataProtectionProviderProtectedData.Protect(String data, String purpose)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessNegotiationRequest(HostContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequest(HostContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.ProcessRequest(HostContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequest(IDictionary`2 environment)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin.Middleware.HubDispatcherMiddleware.Invoke(IOwinContext context)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.OwinMiddlewareTransition.Invoke(IDictionary`2 environment)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.MapMiddleware.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
```

From what I've gathered, SignalR is using the machine key to perform some encryption/decryption.

This is what the machine key looks like:

```
<machineKey decryptionKey="5E329ED7DE2786FCD906E717C97A09BE26B3564BBE0A2B28,IsolateApps" validationKey="A64F709FB47B282CB8331205BC423D63450B4FFC92FE06EC1E00B3AE8B5B1F529A5CD1064F66C08545FC13B013F84153598B29213D5494DD5EC348B537A51DAE,IsolateApps"/>
```

I'm guessing it's seeing the "IsolateApps" in the decryptionKey/validationKey and throwing an exception ("...invalid hex characters").

If I remove the "IsolateApps" from the keys, I can't log in anymore since I'm using FormsAuthentication which in turn makes use of the keys to encrypt/decrypt. So removing the "IsolateApps" does not seem to be a solution.

PS. The code I'm using is from [this](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) tutorial.
I have already looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002960/isolateapps-causes-decryption-key-specified-has-invalid-hex-characters) but it does not solve the problem. I have also tried to add `compatibilityMode="Framework20SP1"` to the machine key but that does not work either.

Is there way to fix this issue without removing the "IsolateApps" value from the keys in the web config?

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the issue. I decided to remove the "`,IsolateApps`" attribute from the machine key which stopped giving this exception:

> Decryption key specified has invalid hex characters

Removing this attribute meant I could not log in anymore (since the machine key has technically changed) which forced me to reset my account password. Once I reset the password I could continue with logging in.

Once I was able to log in I was receiving this error:

> ws://xxxxx/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=xxxxx'
>   failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response.

This exception was only being thrown in Chrome.

SignalR fell back onto server sent events because the web socket handshakes weren't successful. After many hours of debugging I solved the issue by adding this to the web config:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" />
</system.web>
```

Once that was added, SignalR was functioning as excepted.

Comment: Removing IsolateApps worked for me, so thank you. However, I'm still falling back to SSE after making that config change. :(